# "click .className" event in Marionette module is not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, marionette

I have a bit of code that looks something like this

```
myApp.module(args, function(args){
  Views.MainView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    //template, tagName, className
    down: false,
    events: {
      "click .barClassName": "rollUp"
    },

    rollUp: function(){
      if(this.down){
        $(".dropDownDivClass", this.$el).slideUp(200);
        this.down = false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Basically I have a nav bar at the top of my page and each item has an associated drop-down menu. I already implemented the code successfully to make the menus drop down, but I want them to slide back up if I click on a different item. (This ItemView object is on of the items in the nav bar.) Any help with this would be great!
Thanks

Comment: `click` is in events. The click will happen on the nav bar in the DOM.

Comment: without seeing your template, this is hard to answer; however, it could be that .barClassName is not a part of this particular view. The events can only listen to DOM elements that are children of your ItemView.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the animation into onClose(), or possibly onBeforeClose() would be necessary.

```
onClose: function() {
    this.$el.slideUp(200);
}
```

That's assuming that your other code controlling this ItemView is using Marionette's show() to replace which one is displayed. If so, the previous view will be closed before being replaced by the new one. Because of that, you don't need to keep around a flag for if the view is down.

Unless I'm completely misunderstanding how you have this setup. Posting the rest of the code that makes the menus drop down could be useful.